# Multitenant setup with Kibana and Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am going to use logstash+ES+kibana for my project. I want to know how to use this framework for multi tenants. Can any one explain me how after the authentication Kibana query the elastic search index and load in Kibana's dashboard? Can I restrict kibana to look for a specifix index of Elastic search for a particular user or some-id? Anybody has tried this?

Thnx

Comment: Search Guard seems to have support for this: https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard-docs/blob/master/multitenancy.md

Answer (score 4):

You could, but depending on your use case it is probably not a good idea. There are a few gotchas, particularly regarding security and separating the users. First Kibana is just javascript running in the browser. So whatever Kibana is allowed to do so is your user. You can however have a separate index pattern for each "user", but elastic search does not provide you any ways of authenticating a users or authorizing a user access to a specific index. You would have to use some sort of proxy for this.

I recommend http://www.found.no/foundation/elasticsearch-in-production/ and http://www.found.no/foundation/elasticsearch-security/ for a more in depth explanation.

Comment: This is no longer valid with Elastic Shield https://www.elastic.co/products/shield. You can now define user/roles and give them different access levels to specific indexes. It is not open, though.

Answer (score 2):

Create an index for each tenant.

In this way you can use a proxy (like the app the hosts kibana) to intercept the request and return a settings that includes the index to use.

The value that specifies the index to use can be the logged in user or you can get that value somewhere else.

To separate even more the data, you can use a prefix in each index name, and then when you specify an index you can use a pattern to take all the index related to only certain kind of data/entities.

Hope this help.

Comment: Yes, i am doing something in this line. thnx.

Answer (score 1):

Elasticsearch [announced](http://www.elasticsearch.com/blog/shield-know-security-coming-soon/) today a plugin they are working on that should provide security features to ES product. Probably, this will contain ways of restricting access based on roles and users setup at cluster and indices level. If this happens I see no way for them not to extend this security layer to Kibana, as well. Also, it seems this plugin will have a commercial version only.

Comment: sorry for commenting late. But the current elasticsearch security expect user to provide preconfigured path, which won't work here